# How to display alert dialog while connecting to server?

Tags: ios, objective-c

An async request has been sent to the server and here is my connection delegate.
in RKYLoginDelegate.m file, i made an alert to tell user that the member is verifying when receiving data.

didReceivedData

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [_receivedData appendData:data];

    loginAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"message"
                                                message:@"verifying member..."
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [loginAlertView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    NSLog(@"Received data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}
```

and in finish loading data, if nothing return, then shows the error message.
didFinishLoading

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
```

in the code, it will verify return state and parse value, if not respond then alert a dialog to notify user error message

```
if ([jsonDataDictionary count] > 0) {

    // add member into data
    RKYMemberManager *rkyMemberManager = [RKYMemberManager new];
    [rkyMemberManager addMember:jsonDataDictionary];

    // navigate to main
    UIStoryboard *rkyMainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"RKYMainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    RKYMainViewController *rkyMainViewController =
    [rkyMainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RKYMain"];

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController.navigationController presentViewController:rkyMainViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"message"
                              message:@"Cannot login!"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    [alertView show];
    NSLog(@"cannot login");
}
```

Those alert dialogs did show its message, but will cause an error:

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0xc)
```

as title, am I doing correctly?
if yes, how to solve the problem that caused?

Comment: From which place exactly it appears ?

Comment: Don't create so many alert view. You `didReceiveData` method will call many times. So better put you alert message only one time using BOOL condition.

Comment: On which line exactly is the exception thrown?